# How to add StructuredData entities to the ndb.Model using a loop?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I have this question.

I've got two ndb.Models with these properties.

```
class DatesPrices(ndb.Model):
    startDate  = ndb.DateProperty
    endDate    = ndb.DateProperty


class Hotel(ndb.Model):
    datesAndPrices     = ndb.StructuredProperty(DatesPrices, repeated=True)
```

So I need to create a new Hotel Entity, and put several "datesAndPrices'" models in its StructuredProperty property (it can be any amount).

So how can I put it in via a "for loop"?

```
hotel = Hotel()

for x in range(0, someRandomCounter):
    hotel.datesAndPrices.append(DatesPrices(startDate  ='',
                                            startDate  =''));
hotel.put()
????
```

Would this be correct? Can I just append it? Or?

I would appreciate any help! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As soon as you have the StructuredProperty object (that is, `hotel.datesAndPrices`) you can treat it as a Python list.